# Extract attributes of a picture for image recognition

Tags: r, image-processing

My question is inspired by the following Kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/leaf-classification
I have a set of leaves which I would like to classify by how they look like. The classification part I managed to do it by using Random Forests and K-means. However, I am more interested in the pre-processing part so as to replicate this analysis with my own set of pictures.

The characteristics that conform each leaf are given by:

id - an anonymous id unique to an image

margin_1, margin_2, margin_3, ... margin_64 - each of the 64 attribute vectors for the margin feature

shape_1, shape_2, shape_3, ..., shape_64 - each of the 64 attribute vectors for the shape feature

texture_1, texture_2, texture_3, ...,  texture_64 - each of the 64 attribute vectors for the texture feature

So, focusing on the question: I would like to get these characteristics from a raw picture. I have tried with Jpeg R package, but I haven't succeed. I do not show any code I've tried as this is a rather more theoretical question on how to tackle the issue, no need for the code.

I would really appreciate any advise on how to proceed to get the best descriptors of each image.

[image: leaves]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more of which kind of features can you extract based on margin, shape and texture of the images you have (leaves). This depends, some plants can easy be identified with shapes only while others need more features such as texture as they have similar shapes so this is still an open area of research. There have been a number of proposed features for the case of plant species identification which aims to focus on performance, efficiency or usability and good features must be invariant to scale, translation and rotation. Please refer to the link below providing a state-of-art review on the current feature extraction techniques that have been used in plant species identification

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312147459_Plant_Species_Identification_Using_Computer_Vision_Techniques_A_Systematic_Literature_Review